# OAuth2.0 vk.com используя curl и bash

Tags: vkontakte-api, bash, вконтакте, curl, oauth2

Я хочу написать баш скрипт, который будет взаимодействовать с контактом через апи.

Для начала необходимо запрограммировать OAuth2.0 авторизацию. Все казалось бы просто, но проблема в том, что я не могу использовать браузер, так как хочу чтобы мой скрипт работал на юниксовой машине без иксов и без вмешательства пользователя, то есть меня.

Исходя из документация сайта вконтакте сначала я должен выполнить GET запрос:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=<myapp_id>&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&scope=video,audio&response_type=token&v=5.44&revoke=1
```

Этот запрос выполняется нормально и я получаю страницу для отображения пользователю с формами ввода. На данной странице меня интересует только следующий код:

```
<form method="post" action="https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1&utf8=1">
<input type="hidden" name="_origin" value="https://oauth.vk.com">
<input type="hidden" name="ip_h" value="<some_value>" />
<input type="hidden" name="lg_h" value="<some_value>" />
<input type="hidden" name="to" value="<some_value>">
<dl class="fi_row">
<dt class="fi_label">Phone or email:</dt>
<dd>
<div class="iwrap"><input type="text" class="textfield" name="email" value="" /></div>
</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="fi_row">
<dt class="fi_label">Password:</dt>
<dd>
<div class="iwrap"><input type="password" class="textfield" name="pass" /></div>
</dd>
</dl>
<div class="fi_row">
<div class="fi_subrow">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Log in" /><div class="near_btn"><a href="//oauth.vk.com/blank.html#error=access_denied&error_reason=user_denied&error_description=User denied your request">Cancel</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="fi_row_new">
<div class="fi_header fi_header_light">Not registered yet?</div>
</div>
<div class="fi_row">
<a class="button wide_button gray_button" href="https://m.vk.com/join?api_hash=a9612b3095c82d30df">Sign up for VK</a>
</div>
</form>
```

Исходя из документации и этого кода делаю вывод что должен реализовать следующее, то есть отправить пост запрос:

```
https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1&utf8=1
```

и в качестве параметров передать следующие поля:

```
_origin, ip_h, lg_h, to, email, pass
```

Но этот запрос у меня не работает. Возвращается пустая строка при попытке выполнить через curl и страница с ошибкой, мол неправильный пароль если отправляю запрос через какой-нибудь REST клиент. Была мысль что проблема может быть в том, что я не использую куки, но с их добавлением тоже ничего не изменилось, хотя возможно я что-то сделал не так.

Скрипт, который я пытаюсь заставить работать:

```
#!/bin/bash
username=$1
password=$2

response=$(curl --cookie-jar vk.txt "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize" --data "client_id=<app_id>&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&scope=video,audio&response_type=token&v=5.44&revoke=1")
echo "response is $response"
echo "================================================================="
response=$(curl --request POST --cookie vk.txt "https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1&utf8=1" --data-urlencode "_origin=https://oauth.vk.com&ip_h=<some_value>&lg_h=<some_value>&to=<some_value>&email=<my_email>&pass=<my_pass>")
echo "response is $response"
echo "================================================================="

exit 0
```

Я пробовал играться с параметрами curl, например, кодировать, раскодировать передаваемые данные запроса. Но в результате получаю одно и то же. Может быть я должен проводить какое-то дополнительное кодирование или шифрование прежде чем выполнять запрос? Если да, то почему curl не выполняет это по умолчанию?

Я нашел на просторах статью, где эта задача решалась на питоне и у чувака все работает. Я воспользовался его питоновским кодом, переделав его под третий питон, но он также не работает. Возвращает пустую страницу после ввода логина и пароля, хотя должен возвращать страницу с разрешениями для приложения. Мне кажется, что механизм авторизации претерпел некоторые изменения, в связи с чем код перестал работать. Вот ссылка на ту статью:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/143972/

Вообщем вопрос в следующем: как сделать так чтобы всё заработало или что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

А `redirect_uri` у вас соответствует тому, что вы указали при регистрации приложения? Если нет, то проблема в этом.

Comment: Да, redirect_uri соответствует